# Count data between two data ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif, flatten

I've spent countless hours trying to count this data between two date ranges. I'm using a formula I've previously used in the past, but with no luck.

(Fixed - Sample Data - see updated Actual Data below, formula is not working with actual data)
[Current Formula vs. Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGfsK.png)

```
=Query(flatten(filter(E3:E11,D3:D11>=D16,D3:D11<=E16)), "Select Col2,count(Col2) where (Col2 is not null) group by Col2 label count(Col2)''",)
```

I've tried:

1. COUNTIFS but could not find how to include criteria.
2. Using INDIRECT with named range in the 'Expected Results' Reason 1 - Reason 5 Column and COUNTIFS in the column to the right.
3. Googling over 50+ different sites and formulas.

**(Updated: Actual Data) (Error - Not working)**
[Current Formula and Empty Result]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnRkm.png)

The actual data is being pulled from the Data sheet. The data on this sheet looks like this
Data on the Data sheet that's pulled onto the date filter sheet
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZNh9.png)

and is using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(O11:O, ","))="",,TEXT(J11:J,"MM/DD/YYYY")&"×"&L11:L&"×"&M11:M&"×"&N11:N&"×"&SPLIT(O11:O, ","))),"×"),"where Col2 is not null")))
```

Comment: You criteria starts from year 2023 where your all data less than 2023. That is reason to get empty result ny filter formula. Change your date critaria.

Comment: @Harun24hr I just tried that and it worked! This was the sample data I'm using, when I apply this same formula to my actual data, it returns the same empty result.

I just updated my post I apologize for the simple mistake on the sample data!

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook so that we can check it?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I used the same code I previously used. However, the dates that were being selected could not be selected with the data that was being pulled.

I used:

```
=INT(O3)
```

to copy the date into another column, dragged the formula down, and used the filter to select the date from this new column. The date filter then worked.